# How I can enable mouse middle button in my touch mouse lenovo yoga laptop?

Tags: laptop, mouse

I am working with Pymol and I need to move or drag the molecule but I couldn't do it with my Lenovo Yoga Laptop[touch pad in my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf8iE.jpg)
Would you please help in that
Thanks
Fawzia

Answer (score 0):

To enable Mouse middle button in touchpad go to your settings>devices>touchpad Scroll down and find the “Three-finger gestures” section. Click the “Taps” box and select “Middle mouse button”.